# configure rewrite rules in iis for arabic wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an arabic wordpress website that I recently deployed on iis

the main problems now that

1- all categories with arabic names show 404
2- all posts with arabic title encode the url to something like ?%3F%3F-%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F-%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F-%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F-%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%2F and does not open anything

I have tried many codes for rwrite rules like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 1999-2019. Plesk International GmbH. All rights reserved. -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension="."/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://localhost:8080" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but none of them works with me

EDIT : the solution was in this post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245111/arabic-permalink-not-found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you said,the issue is caused due to IIS does not recognize the multiple language URLs. I suggest you try to configure `.Net globalization` to achieve that.
[image]
Alternatively,

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I don’t know if these settings work on the website based on another programming language, please let me know if it works. Besides, you could post your solution as the answer to your question so that we can help other guys who ran into the same issue.

Comment: This is not working with me, and although the posts and categories are working fine now but images still have the problem if it contains arabic character

Comment: Does not work with Django.